# DPSET: Multiple connections in Ryu SDN Controller

Tags: sdn, ryu

I install latest Ryu controller from pip install(Python3) in Ubuntu 14.04 on VM(VM-A), and NIC configure as bridge mode(192.168.88.252).

I assume VM-A's host is "Host-A"

And connect physical Zodiac FX Openflow switch, port4(reserve for connect with controller, 192.168.88.252) to router(192.168.88.0/24)

Zodiac FX port3 connect to router(192.168.88.0/24)

And connect Two RPI(AKA Host-B,C) on Zodiac FX port 1,2(so, two rpi will get 192.168.88.250, 192.168.88.249)

And connect controller Host-A to router(192.168.88.253)

It work fine, and two rpi able to connect internet.

Host-A able to connect two rpi.
But if I trying to use VM-A to do any kind of connect with two rpi.

Hole controller will stuck for few minute, an get message:

> DPSET: Multiple connections {dpid}

I wounder to know there is illegal when I using SDN controller to communicate with openflow networking devices?

In my case, my ryu app run simple_switch_13.py.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I spread another subnet(192.168.80.0/24) for sdn switch communicate with controller.

This problem solved!, SDN controller need another NIC to connect another subnet.

I still can using SDN controller access 192.168.88.0/24 without DPSET problem.